# Can't grab value-of content:encoded from Wordpress RSS

Tags: xml, wordpress, xslt, rss

I have this XSLT file that I'm using to translate Wordpress articles from a category RSS feed (namely [this one](http://cas.illinoisstate.edu/sites/wgs/category/wgs-news/feed)). Mostly everything is working the way it should, expect for when I'm trying to get the value of the "content:encoded" element using `xsl:value-of`. Nothing is returned when I use the following code. Is there something that I'm missing, or is the colon in "content:encoded" messing up the XSLT?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>


<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" version="1.0"
     exclude-result-prefixes="dc">
<xsl:output method = "html" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
<xsl:param name="limit"></xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="hide">none</xsl:param>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="rss/channel/item">
        <xsl:variable name="link" select="link"/>

        <xsl:element name="a">
            <xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of select="link"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="title" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <br />
        <xsl:value-of select="content:encoded" />

    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanks much.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ended up finding out that the colon was doing funky namespace stuff. Silly Wordpress. So I ended up using `*[name()='content:encoded']` instead of just `content:encoded`.